# How to unit test database queries based on current date?

Tags: database, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Is there a feasible way of testing SQL queries that contain things like `CURRENT_DATE` and `NOW()` in a unit test?

For example:

```php
public function deletePastEntries(): bool {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM queue WHERE period_end < NOW();";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->execute();
}
```

And in my unit test:

```php
class QueueTest extends AbstractDatabaseTestCase
{
    // ...<snip>...boilerplate stuff

    public function testDeletePastEntries(): void {
        $this->object->deletePastEntries();

        $actualTable = $this->getConnection()->createQueryTable('queue', 'SELECT id, user, period_start, period_end FROM queue ORDER BY id;');

        $expectedTable = $this->createArrayDataSet([
            'queue' => [/* stuff that should remain */]
        ])->getTable('queue');

        static::assertTablesEqual($expectedTable, $actualTable);
    }
}
```

I have tagged PHPUnit but this question should be generic enough for any kind of database testing.

For mocking usages of things like `new \DateTime()` (defaulting to "now"), I can change the function to accept a parameter. I suppose I can change all the queries to take a parameter instead of `NOW()` or time-dependent functions, but I'm not sure if changing all the queries for this purpose is the right way going forward, especially for things that do not make sense to pass in arbitrary dates/times. In addition, using parameters would mean that I have to construct the values of those parameters in the application and pass them in.

Comment: What about generating the relevant  database contents on the fly in preparation of the test?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - That's a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

Make the functions that should use "current date" receive a parameter for it, and default it to current date. Something like below:

```
public function deletePastEntries($now = null)
{
    if (! $now) {
        $now = time();
    }

    $sql = "DELETE FROM queue WHERE period_end < ?;";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->execute($now);
}
```

Now you can pass a fixed date as "current date" in tests, or just pass nothing and run with the actual current date otherwise.

Another popular approach is to not use `now()` except in one place, and use your own `myNow()` everywhere instead:

```
public function deletePastEntries()
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM queue WHERE period_end < ?;";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->execute(myNow());
}

// Elsewhere:
public function myNow() {
  return now();
}

// For tests, redefine it:
public function myNow() {
  return WELL_KNOWN_MOMENT_CONST;
}
```

Depending on which version of `myNow()` is available in the global context, you have either current time, or predictable constant time.

Instead of topmost level function, you can use a more specific shared / top-level configuration object, which is also a popular pattern:

```
...execute($global_config->now());
```

Comment: It's not ideal to pass a parameter in a test that isn't passed in production, since then the code path being tested isn't the same one that runs in production and the test has limited value.

I would probably inject an object representing either the current time or a clock into the constructor. If you're using a service container then it should be able to do that injection in production, and you'll pass a fixed value time or a fake clock manually for a unit test.

For instance if we accidentally type `$now = tiem();` the unit test won't fail, since that line isn't covered.

Comment: @bdsl: If you have an object with a constructor, you can inject data into it. But please note that you'd have to have a parameter to inject to. But your critique does have a merit: instead of passing a clock to a particular function, you can replace the clock in the global context. I'm updating my answer.